# twig: appending to parent template region from multiple includes

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

general.tpl:

```
<head>
    <!-- some default meta tags -->
</head>
<body>
    {% block mainArea %}{% endblock  %}
    {% block sidebar %}{% endblock  %}
    <!-- standard footer -->
    <script src="base.js"></script>
    {% block js %}{% endblock  %}
</body>
```

page1.tpl:

```
{% extends "base.tpl" %}

{% block mainArea %}
    some content
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
    ...
    {% include 'one-of-many-widgets.tpl' %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

**one-of-many-widgets.tpl**

1. requires specific javascript library that must be referenced before `<body>` tag and needs to emit specific in-line javascript before that library but after referencing `base.js`
2. requres specific meta tags to be added to page `head` block
3. requires to append additional legal information to page footer

Q1: How to do that by putting additional script and meta info **into `one-of-many-widgets.tpl`** file? Given that there is several included widgets that all contribute to scripts area of page.

Q2: there is also page2.tpl, that also need it's own additional js and extended meta tags, in addition to emitted by includes. Is it possible to combine them but not overwrite?

one-of-many-widgets-1.tpl:

```
{% block jsPreBodyAdditions %}
    {{ alreadyCollected() }} widget script tag or inline js to APPEND
{% endblock %}
{% block metaTags %}
    {{ alreadyCollected() }} widget additional semantic meta tags to APPEND
{% endblock %}
```

one-of-many-widgets-2.tpl:

```
{% block jsPreBodyAdditions %}
    {{ alreadyCollected() }} widget script tag or inline js to APPEND
{% endblock %}
{% block metaTags %}
    {{ alreadyCollected() }} widget additional semantic meta tags to APPEND
{% endblock %}
```

page2.tpl:

```
{% block jsPreBodyAdditions %}
    {{ alreadyCollected() }} page2 script tag or inline js to APPEND
{% endblock %}
{% block metaTags %}
    {{ alreadyCollected() }} page2 additional semantic meta tags to APPEND
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Q1: you can put an empty section in the base(main) tpl and override only in the child that need to add some data. Q2: yes, of course. Remember exist the [parent twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html) that render the father block content. Hope this help

Comment: I know about that. But I can not make a sidebar widget to extend from something, this is compositional component, so I include it. How can I collect specific output from multiple *includes* and child page and parent page and then append/prepend it to block of parent page?